# Long but shallow hardwood floor damage

Tags: hardwood-floor

The son of a friend of a friend dragged a chair with an unprotected bottom across the length of our living room (about 20 feet) leaving highly noticeable but very very shallow scratches on the floor.

[image]

We live in a rental flat --- so short of a major project that would require the landlord's approval, is there anyway to minimize the appearance of this damage to the floor?